# Excel 2007 - convert column to date format ddmmyyyyhh24miss

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel 2007, I have a date column with value "05/26/2013 23:30:45" which should be converted to "26052013233045" i.e of "ddmmyyyyhh24mmss" format.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this custom format to the cell: `ddmmyyyyhhmmss` Your data would be displayd as you want.

Use on Cell `right click -> format cells - > number -> custom`

Comment: i tried this already but with no desired result. But this is successful on a single  windows xp 32 bit machine in my office where as in another four to 5 machines of windows 7/windows server 2008  machines this did not work out . I am confused if its an excel issue or something to do with the operating system .

Comment: On those systems it did not work at all? If so, try having a look at the content of cell with the date in the Formula Bar. If your date apears in the Formula Bar like this: '05/26/2013 23:30:45 try removing the ' at the begining of the data. This sign ' tells Excel to always treat the content as text.

Comment: I did as u said and now it works !!! But got another problem .. all the selected cells are not changing .. i need to place the cursor on the cell and double click on the cell content for date format change !!!!

Comment: You can try to copy that column to another empty column next to that, and use paste special to copy only the values. This should remove ' sign. Then delete the first column and you remain with the new one.